# installing flutter when anaconda is already installed

Tags: flutter, anaconda

Hi im trying to install `flutter`. I have Anaconda already installed on my MacBook and it is in my `.zshrc` file.
It currently has this in the file.

```bash
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/Users/curtissanderson/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.zsh' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/curtissanderson/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Users/curtissanderson/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/Users/curtissanderson/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

I would like to add the flutter Path but don't know where I should add it. Can anyone help that would be great thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the path at the end. Make a new line after "# <<< conda initialize <<< " and paste the following:

export PATH="$PATH:[PATH_OF_FLUTTER_GIT_DIRECTORY]/bin"

Then replace [PATH_OF_FLUTTER_GIT_DIRECTORY] with the path in your computer and restart the terminal.

Following this worked for me.